# Sacar ID de un elemento que está antes con JQuery

Tags: jquery

Vereis, quiero hacer que cuando clicken el botón con id="show_message", muestre el id del elemento **span** que está dentro del elemento **td**.

Code de la página:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Code Jquery:

```
$('#show_message').click(function () {
   alert($(this).find('#ini_name').children('span').attr('id'));
});
```

He probado también con **parent** en vez de **find** para descarta, y nada.

Comment: mejora tu pregunta porfavor, no entiendo **que está por encima:** ?

Comment: Está bien, la editaré para dejar más claro lo que pretendo hacer, sorry.

Comment: era preferible cuando era texto y no la imagen

Comment: Era para enfatizar sobre que hay mas elementos **td** entre el boton y el td con id ini_name.

Comment: Creo que lo que tienes es un problema de organización o de lógica en el código. ¿Eso es un formulario, una tabla, o qué es? Si organizaras mejor (con formularios, con clases...), podrías acceder más fácil a los elementos, sin tener que dar tantas vueltas.

Comment: Estoy usando el plugin DataTables para crear una tabla que la lleno con información sacada de una base de datos. 

Seguiré tu consejo y probaré de reestructurar el código y eliminar las IDs como forma de indentificar las partes. 

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error al utilizar `find` es que la función busca entre los descendientes del elemento en donde se le indica, en tu caso lo estaba haciendo desde el `input`, nunca lo encontrará como descendiente suyo. Hice un ejemplo para que veas cómo acceso al id que deseas, el único truco es navegar correctamente entre los elementos:

```js
$('input[id^="show_message"]').click(function() {
  alert($(this).parent('td').prev().children('span').attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="ini_name1">
      <span id="spanid1">span ejemplo</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="show_message1" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Show">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="ini_name2">
      <span id="spanid2">span ejemplo</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="show_message2" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Show">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="ini_name3">
      <span id="spanid3">span ejemplo</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="show_message3" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Show">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Por otro lado, para lo que necesitas es más comodo trabajar con clases en lugar de ids:

```js
$('.show_message').click(function() {
  alert($(this).parent('td').prev().children('span').attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="ini_name">
      <span id="spanid1">span ejemplo</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="show_message" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Show">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ini_name">
      <span id="spanid2">span ejemplo</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="show_message" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Show">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ini_name">
      <span id="spanid3">span ejemplo</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="show_message" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Show">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Lo he probado, pero cuando lo ejecuto me sale "undefined". Comentarte de que no hay solo 2 **td** sino varios, así que he tratado de editar tu code para adaptarlo: 

alert($(this).parent('td').prev().find('#ini_name').children('span').attr('id'));

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para que veas que funciona aunque los ids varien, la causa por la que podría no funcionarte es que en tu código original tienes errores con las comillas en los ids

Comment: Pero piensa que solo hay un botón, con tu Jquery cada botón apunta al td anterior y así sí que lo puedes sacar, la cosa és que solo tiene que haber uno.

Comment: mmm.. ¿solo un boton? Pero, si solo hay un boton y multiples spans ¿cual span es el que se va a mostrar entonces? ¿El ultimo?

Comment: Con Jquery la idea es que viaje al span con el id=ini_name y extraiga el id del span que tiene. Yo sigo intentando pero solo recibo "undefined" como output del alert.

Comment: Ok , eso está claro pero, según veo el span lo generas en un for, entonces son varios span, si quieres encontrar el id(el cual debe ser unico) encontrará varios. No me queda claro lo que necesitas entonces

Comment: Genero un <tr> y en cada <tr> se generan diferentes <td> con información, cada <td> contiene un único botón para sacar el id del span que está dentro de ini_name. 

De todas formas, reestructuraré el código como bien me aconsejais y trataré de intentarlo de nuevo.

Gracias y siento no haber expresado muy bien mi problema desde el principio.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo logré, utilicé parte de tu code y cambié las IDs por clases y en vez de parent use parents, etc. 

El caso es que ya funciona, gracias ^^!

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejo que leas y sobretodo entiendas la documentación de Jquery.

También que escribas código html bien formado porque si no lo está el DOM no estará completo y fallará javascript.

Para el código que pones sería algo así:

```
 $("#show_message").click( function()
 {
    alert($('#ini_name span').attr('id'));
 });
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo completo aqui.
http://tpcg.io/0pGOA2

Comment: stackoverflow cuenta con su propio editor de snippets